# How to suppress the 'Building x%' message when running the Gradle JavaExec task to capture user input?

Tags: gradle, gradlew

Is it possible to suppress the `'Building x%'` message when running a Gradle JavaExec task to capture user input?

I'm having a custom JavaExec task like:

```
task runApp(type: JavaExec) {
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    main = "RSBot"
    standardInput = System.in
}
```

It uses the `standardInput` to capture user input.
The user input is captured until the process is exited.

The problem the JavaExec task keeps displaying a `> Building 87% > :rivescript-samples-rsbot:runApp` message at the bottom which is quite annoying as the user need to enter the input there.

Look at the example below.

```
$ ./gradlew :rivescript-samples-rsbot:runApp
:rivescript-core:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:rivescript-core:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:rivescript-core:classes UP-TO-DATE
:rivescript-core:jar UP-TO-DATE
:rivescript-samples-rsbot:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:rivescript-samples-rsbot:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:rivescript-samples-rsbot:classes UP-TO-DATE
:rivescript-samples-rsbot:runApp
      .   .       
     .:...::      RiveScript Java // RSBot
    .::   ::.     Version: 0.6.0
 ..:;;. ' .;;:..  
    .  '''  .     Type '/quit' to quit.
     :;,:,;:      Type '/help' for more options.
     :     :      

:: Creating RS Object
:: Loading replies
You> 
> BuiBot> How do you do. Please state your problem.   
You> 
> BuiBot> Please go on.   pt-samples-rsbot:runApphelp
You> 
> BuiBot> You're now playing the game. Type "help" for help.

You are in the lobby of a NASA launch base on Earth. There is an elevator to the north.   
You> 
> Building 87% > :rivescript-samples-rsbot:runApp
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Mr Haki pointed out to me the `--console plain` command line option does the trick.

```
./gradlew :rivescript-samples-rsbot:runApp --console plain
```

Comment: Did you find a way to specify this in the task?

Comment: No unfortunately not.